# Modify a control's action in an inherited form so that it acquires the new action's events

Tags: forms, delphi, inheritance, action, eventhandler

I have an ancestor form with some controls on it, some of them are associated with actions so they "acquire" their action's events (i.e. a button acquires the action's OnExecute event on its OnClick event).

Then I have another form that inherits from this one. I want one of the inherited buttons to behave differently from what's in the ancestor (yes I know, this is not good practice, but let's concentrate on the topic), so I create a new action and its OnExecute event, then set the button's action to the new one. Check if the button's OnClick event points to the new OnExecute event handler and it seems all fine.

Run the program, click on the button and surprise, the executed code is the one from the ancestor's action, not my new one!

Double check the new form, seems ok... But if I close and reopen it in the IDE, I can see the OnClick event handler of my button actually points to event handler acquired from the ancestor action, not from my new one.

The problem probably lies on the fact that the OnClick event handler, being acquired from the action, is not written to the DFM file, so when my inherited form is loaded, the OnClick event on my button isn't defined and is inherited from the ancestor form. Am I correct?

But then, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the new action to the button (e.g. in FormCreate, after inherited)?

Comment: This doesn't sound very plausible. I suspect that there is something in your project interfering with things.

Comment: What about moving the ancestor form's `OnExecute` logic into a virtual method that the ancestor button action calls, and then the derived form can override that method, so it doesn't have to deal with the button or the action directly.

Comment: The only time I have experienced this type of thing is when I inadvertently had open an old version of the form (to do so comparisons with what I had changed). So I was not working on the version of the form I thought I was. This scenario would account for what you are seeing (on reopening the form you open the correct one!)

Comment: @Remy Don't see that you'd have too. But in any case you can just hide the base class event handler because the form connects them using RTTI.

Comment: Like David Hefferman said: just double click the actions OnExecute event in the property inspector when you’re in the child form and you get a new OnExecute handle which will overwrite the parent event handle. And if you also want the parents event handler to be ex3cute, just call ‘inherited’.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, was on holiday. @Mark yes this was exactly my workaround and it works, though I'd like to know if there's a design time solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's exactly as it is. After seeing this on my bug project, I've tried on a test one, only a base form and an inherited one, it behaves like I said.

Comment: @RemyLebeau your solution sounds good and quite elegant ;)

Comment: Also hiding the ancestor's event handler seems OK, as long as the ancestor doesn't call it programmatically. I'll try it anyway.

Comment: You are right. This looks like a clear defect in the IDE. You should submit a bug report. Remy's solution works fine but maybe slight overkill. Hiding the ancestor's handler works because the handlers are wired up using RTTI, which finds the hiding method. As you say, if the ancestor calls the event handler directly then that's a problem. I always call `Action1.Execute` if I want to fire and event in code. And that would work perfectly well. You've got a clear understanding of all this now.